# create dynamic views from alternating staging table names stored in a variable

Tags: ssis

I would like to create views dynamically like this:

```
CREATE VIEW V_Customer
AS SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Country
FROM CustomerStagingTable1

CREATE VIEW V_Customer
AS SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Country
FROM CustomerStagingTable2
```

in an 'Execute SQL Task' where the strings: 'CustomerStagingTable1' and 'CustomerStagingTable2' should come from a variable. Could I 'inject' the strings in the same way as I would do it for WHERE CLAUSES:

```
WHERE A = ?
```

So using:

```
CREATE VIEW V_Customer
AS SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Country
FROM ?
```

Comment: If you downvote - pls specify why ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I solved it like this

```
CREATE VIEW V_Customer
AS 

SELECT Source = 1, First_Name, Last_Name, Country
FROM CustomerStagingTable1

UNION ALL

SELECT Source = 2, First_Name, Last_Name, Country
FROM CustomerStagingTable2

GO


SELECT *
FROM V_Customer
WHERE Source = ?
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this a scalable approach, as this involves a union and than a where?

Comment: I did a small test and examined the execution plan and saw that SQL searches through one staging table.